# Is there any way to get data from one API that is dependent on another API in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way for retrieving the items from one API call and that API is dependent on another API call.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am making an API call from which I am getting an **url** and from that url I want **item-name**.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'd need to work with futures and async calls, the `then()` and `catchError()` methods, so when you get one answer from the first api, you call the second, and use the `then()` method again. It's important for you to edit your question and add the code of what you have tried so we can help properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, create two methods to call each API

```
Future<String> makeFirstCall() {
  String url;

  url = // Call your first api and return the url

  return url;
}

Future<String> makeSecondCall(String url) {
  // Call your second API with the given url and return the item-name
}
```

Then in your code make the following call to chain both apis:

```
makeFirstCall().then((url) => 
  makeSecondCall(url).then((itemName) {
    // Use itemName to do whatever you want
  });
);
```

You can also use `await` instead of `then()`

```
String url = await makeFirstCall();
String itemName = await makeSecondCall(url);
// Use itemName to do whatever you want
```

Comment: can anyone give full example for this

Comment: How is this code not complete ? Do you mean that your initial question is not just about the way to chain two API calls, but to help you call an you don't know how to call an API also ?

Comment: What is the method to call 4 apis and retrieve the results in form of a list of all 4 apis

Comment: apply the same method as above, but for 4 apis instead of 2.